# Fragment BackStack dont work although addToBackStack(null) is called

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Activity I call:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new UserPlaylistsFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This fragment is added correctly to the view.
The fragment contains a listview. When an item is clicked the following code will be executed:

```
getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ViewPlaylistFragment(),
                    "ViewPlaylistFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This works too. The UserPlaylistsFragment gets replaced with the ViewPlaylistFragment. 
The strange thing:
When hitting the "Back-Button" nothing happens. And when hitting it twice, the app closes (without errors).

It seems that the "BackStack" doesnt work for me. Anyone some suggestions?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This might be a long shot, but i've seen fragments act crazy.
Why are you doing `.addToBackStack(null)` twice? You should only call it after the `add` or `replace`

Comment: The double `.addToBackStack(null)` looks weird to me as well. Did you try using only the one just before the commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your first call to .addToBackStack(null) in your initial FragmentTransaction.

Comment: Wow this question is long ago but ofc you are right, the double backstack call was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Never call addToBackStack() twise.. it would mess it up